# IOS Category on NSArray Causes "instance message does not declare a method with selector"

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, categories

I am trying to use the Category described in this article:
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/shuffling-arrays.html

I have setup the following:

```
//  NSArray+Shuffle.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface NSArray (Shuffle)
-(NSArray *)shuffledArray;
@end


//  NSArray+Shuffle.m
#import "NSArray+Shuffle.h"
@implementation NSArray (Shuffle)
-(NSArray *)shuffledArray
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self count]];
    NSMutableArray *copy = [self mutableCopy];
    while ([copy count] > 0)
    {
        int index = arc4random() % [copy count];
        id objectToMove = [copy objectAtIndex:index];
        [array addObject:objectToMove];
        [copy removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
// Using IOS 5 ARC
//    [copy release];
return array;
}
@end
```

Then in my code that I want to use this, I imported the Category:

```
#import "NSArray+Shuffle.h"
```

Then, I attempted to use it like this:

```
    NSArray *orderedGallary = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  @"Pic1", @"pageName",
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pic1.jpg"],@"pageImage",
                  nil],
                 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  @"Pic2", @"pageName",
                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pic2.jpg"],@"pageImage",
                  nil],

                 nil];   

    NSArray *shuffler = [[NSArray alloc] shuffledArray:orderedGallary];

    _pageData = [shuffler shuffledArray:orderedGallary];
```

But, I get the following compiler error message:

```
ModelController.m: error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Receiver type 'NSArray' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'shuffledArray:'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shuffledArray` is a method that takes no parameters, it is different from `shuffledArray:`, which is a method that takes one parameter.

It looks like what you meant was:

```
NSArray* shuffled = [orderedGallery shuffledArray];
```

Here you are sending this message to your original array, and it returns a new array that is shuffled.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for lesson/explanation.  It's makes complete sense now that you described it.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared (in the .h) and defined (in the .m) a method named `shuffledArray`.

You are calling a method named `shuffledArray:` (notice the colon, which indicates an argument).

You want to be calling

```
NSArray *shuffled = [orderedGallery shuffledArray];
```

you don't need the argument because you are sending the method to the ordered array.

(There's no object that's actually a "shuffler" - independent of the array - so **I** wouldn't use that name as the variable name.  The array is shuffling a copy of itself and returning the new shuffled array.)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying too hard. You only need to send `-shuffledArray` to `orderedGallery`.

```
NSArray *orderedGallary = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
             [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              @"Pic1", @"pageName",
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pic1.jpg"],@"pageImage",
              nil],
             [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              @"Pic2", @"pageName",
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pic2.jpg"],@"pageImage",
              nil],

             nil];   

_pageData = [orderedGallery shuffledArray];
```

See how you have declared `shuffledArray` not to take any arguments? Simply sending this message to any instance of `NSArray` will return your shuffled array.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I was trying too hard.  Thanks for clarification.  I have implemented the above suggestion.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

shuffledArray does not take a parameter but is called directly on the array:

```
NSArray *myShuffledArray = [orderedGallery shuffledArray]
```